# What is the difference between academic and general English?

Tags: terminology

What is the difference between academic and general English? why is there academic English in the first place and not just general English?

Comment: Where have you seen "academic English" used?  Are you asking about *Academic English* in the context of *English for specific purposes* (ESP)?

Answer (score 2):

When writing in an academic context you will write *formally*  (and avoid slang and casual phrases) and you will probably use subject-specific *jargon* and *technical terms*.

For example:

> Viruses rely on host metabolism for replication. Here, the authors perform transcriptional and metabolomic analyses at 8 hours after SARS-CoV-2 infection and find that the virus alters host folate and one-carbon metabolism at a post-transcriptional level.

The writers here are using formal English, including the particular academic style of using the third person to refer themselves (*the authors*) and technical terms like "folate" and "post-transcriptional" that have a special meaning to people who study viruses. And generally the style is formal: they wrote the more formal "perform" and "find" instead of "do" and "find out".

Answer (score 1):

Academic English is not a version of English the way British/American is. It just means that you are writing in an academic context (having to do with education/research) and will thus use a particular type of formal and specific writing.